# adding Key values from NSDictionary to NSarray

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to add all the keys from the dictionary to the array. This is what I am doing right now.As code below:

```
for (NSString * akey in _groups ) {

    NSLog(@"%@",akey);
    [_groupArray addObject:akey];
    NSLog(@"%@",_groupArray);
}
```

The log is showing Null for _groupArray. I even tried using `insertObjectAtIndex` even that does not work.Not sure what I am doing wrong and yes I am getting the keys in the dictionary (_groups) nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize the array before starting to add values to it. Otherwise it is initially `nil` and will remain `nil`.

You can use `allKeys` to get all the keys of the array. But since `_groupArray` is an `NSMutableArray`, you have to do that like this:

```
_groupArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_groups allKeys]];
```

Or:

```
_groupArray = [[_groups allKeys] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: yea figured that out - but i am getting a warning now - "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutuableArray *__ strong' from 'NSArray'" how can i get rid of this ?

Comment: @Gaurav_soni - See my updated answer. If this still doesn't work, can you update your question with the code that you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

If _groupsArray is new or empty anyway then you can use

```
_gropusArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allKeys]];
```

That should release you from the compiler warning.

If _groupsArray was not empty before and you need to addValues then go for:

```
[_groupsArray addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you should do it....

```
_groupsArray=[dict allKeys];
```

don't forget to allocate memory to your _groupsArray.. :)

Comment: yea figured that out - but i am getting a warning now - "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutuableArray *__ strong' from 'NSArray'" how can i get rid of this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you've alloc'd and init'd your mutable array. Unless there's already stuff in it that you're adding to - and even then - consider using the NSDictiomary allKeys method rather than iterating through the dictionary.

From the docs

**allKeys**

Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.

```
- (NSArray *) allKeys
```

**Return Value**

A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.

**Discussion**

The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Comment: yea figured that out - but i am getting a warning now - "incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutuableArray *__ strong' from 'NSArray'" how can i get rid of this ?